# How to minimize if else code to Bitwise

Tags: c, pic, mplab

is there possible to simplify this statement ?

There are same if I using the case statement and while loop.

```
void decode (unsigned char* msg) {


     if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x00") != NULL) // 0
     {
        //00000
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
     else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x01") != NULL)// 1
     {
        //00001
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
         else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x02") != NULL)// 2
     {
        //00010
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x03") != NULL)// 3
     {
        //00011
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x04") != NULL)// 4
     {
        //00100
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x05") != NULL)// 5
     {
        //00101
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x06") != NULL)// 6
     {
        //00110
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x07") != NULL)// 7
     {
        //00111
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x08") != NULL)// 8
     {
        //01000
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x09") != NULL)// 9
     {
        //01001
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0A") != NULL)// 10
     {
        //01010
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0B") != NULL)// 11
     {
        //01011
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0C") != NULL)// 12
     {
        //01100
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0D") != NULL)// 13
     {
        //01101
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0E") != NULL)// 14
     {
        //01110
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0F") != NULL)// 15
     {
        //01111
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 1 ; //DO5 OFF
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x10") != NULL)// 16
     {
        //10000
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 O1
     }
             else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x11") != NULL)// 17
     {
        //10001
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x12") != NULL)// 18
     {
        //10010
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x13") != NULL)// 19
     {
        //10011
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x14") != NULL)// 20
     {
        //10100
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x15") != NULL)// 21
     {
        //10101
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x16") != NULL)// 22
     {
        //10110
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x17") != NULL)// 23
     {
        //10111
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x18") != NULL)// 24
     {
        //11000
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x19") != NULL)// 25
     {
        //11001
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1A") != NULL)// 26
     {
        //11010
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1B") != NULL)// 27
     {
        //11011
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1C") != NULL)// 28
     {
        //11100
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1D") != NULL)//29
     {
        //11101
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1E") != NULL)// 30
     {
        //11110
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
                else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1F") != NULL)// 31
     {
        //11111
        LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 ON
        LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 ON
        LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 ON
        LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 ON
        LATGbits.LATG12   = 0 ; //DO5 ON
     }
}
```

The above code shows, when the word is write in HyperTerminal, it will do some action to LED. For example, DO=0x1F will turn on all five LED. Because, based on the 0x1F in binary is IIIII (5-Bit). Is there any ways to simplify the code using Bitwise function ?

Comment: This looks inconsistent.  `LATG0 == 0` implies D02 is `ON`, but `LATG1 == 0` implies D01 is `OFF`? Really?

Comment: Yes, `LATG0 == 0` implies D02 is `on`. I already check on the hardware and schematic that the manufacture used that code.

Comment: what `msg` will contain?

Comment: @venki the msg will contain, what string the user write in HyperTerminal.

Comment: if I write `0x0` what you are expecting ?

Comment: @venki I guess there are nothing happened to the LED.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but here's how to approach the problem:

1. Build and hardcode a lookup table of 32 values that contains the desired bit flags for each hex value, stored as an `int`.
2. Parse the `msg` and extract the hex value (`0x00 - 0x1F`) as an `int`.
3. Use the value from step to as an index into the table to select the desired bits (the `int`)
4. Apply those values to the `LATGbits` structure members as appropriate.

Comment: what should the value in lookup table, for example `DO=0x08`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can declare an int value D which will contain the hexadicimal value to represent the input from the hyperterminal;
After that you may use this value to bind each bit to the corresponding LED. You can try this code:

```
    LATGbits.LATG1    = (D & 0x01) ; //DO1
    LATGbits.LATG0    = !(D>>1 & 0x01); //DO2
    LATGbits.LATG13   = !(D>>2 & 0x01) ; //DO3
    LATGbits.LATG14   = !(D>>3 & 0x01) ; //DO4
    LATGbits.LATG12   = !(D>>4 & 0x01); //DO5
```

Comment: for LATG0 ,13,14, and 12 . Is that same with `LATGbits.LATG0  = (D >> 1) & 1`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question!
The (D>> i & 0x01) is used to check whether the i-th bit of the variable D is set to 1, if it's so it will return 1 , else it will return 0.
So for LATG14 for example you need to check the 4th bit so you need to shift by 3 bits and see if it's 1 or 0.

Comment: thanks for explaining. But, how to declare an int value D from the hyperterminal that we write ?

Answer (score 0):

From your code i guess that you are using a PIC microprocessor. There should be a LATG register which you can use to manipulate the code.

I have given an example for the first case, In each case, you first bitwise AND with a mask of 1FFC, then you bitwise OR with a mask depending on the bits that you require to be 1 for that case.

```
if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x00") != NULL) // 0
{
    //11....01
    LATG = LATG & 0x1FFC;  // 0001 1111 1111 1110
    LATG = LATG | 0xE001;  // 1110 0000 0000 0001
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
char *eptr = NULL;
int assignThese[] = { 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x07, 0x17, 0x0B, 0x1B, 0x03, 0x13, 0x0d, 0x1d, 0x15 /** Remaining Values Here */ };
/* Or whichever function to parse integer section */
int index         = (int)strtol ( msg+4 , &eptr , 16 ) ;

   /* Some bit manipulations */
    LATGbits.LATG1    = (assignThese[index]&0x10)>>4 ; 
    LATGbits.LATG0    = (assignThese[index]&0x08)>>3 ; 
    LATGbits.LATG13   = (assignThese[index]&0x04)>>2 ; 
    LATGbits.LATG14   = (assignThese[index]&0x02)>>1 ; 
    LATGbits.LATG12   = (assignThese[index]&0x01) ;
```

Just a question why can't you pass the Hexadecimal Number as an integer to this function instead.

Comment: Uday: If i write `DO=0x05 `there are nothing happend. How to set the `msg`?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your case but probably you need to find a way to extract hexa-decimal part along with 'DO=0x' and copy it to msg using memcpy for instance and call sequence of commands above.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add a function with an argument as msg of int type as below, and call it when according to it. But optimizing if and else condition is not possible as no sequential assigning is done so only number of statement can be decrease.

```
void LATG(unsigned int msg)
{
    LATGbits.LATG1    = (msg >> 0 & 1) ; //DO1
    LATGbits.LATG0    = (msg >> 1 & 1) ; //DO2
    LATGbits.LATG13   = (msg >> 2 & 1) ; //DO3
    LATGbits.LATG14   = (msg >> 3 & 1) ; //DO4
    LATGbits.LATG12   = (msg >> 4 & 1) ; //DO5
}

void decode (unsigned char* msg) 
{
 if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x00") != NULL) // 0
 { 
     LATG(30);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x01") != NULL)// 1
 {
    //00001
     LATG(32);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x02") != NULL)// 2
 {
    //00010
     LATG(28);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x03") != NULL)// 3
 {
    //00011
             LATG(29);
 }
  else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x04") != NULL)// 4
 {
    //00100
         LATG(26);
 }
  else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x05") != NULL)// 5
 {
    //00101
             LATG(27);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x06") != NULL)// 6
 {
    //00110
             LATG(24);
 }
  else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x07") != NULL)// 7
 {
    //00111
             LATG(25);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x08") != NULL)// 8
 {
    //01000
             LATG(22);
 }
  else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x09") != NULL)// 9
 {
    //01001
             LATG(23);
 }
         else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0A") != NULL)// 10
 {
    //01010
             LATG(23);
 }
  else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0B") != NULL)// 11
 {
    //01011
             LATG(21);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0C") != NULL)// 12
 {
    //0110
             LATG(6);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0D") != NULL)// 13
 {
    //01101
             LATG(19);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0E") != NULL)// 14
 {
    //01110
    LATG(16);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x0F") != NULL)// 15
 {
    //01111
    LATG(17);
 }
         else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x10") != NULL)// 16
 {
    //10000
    LATG(14);
 }
         else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x11") != NULL)// 17
 {
    //10001
    LATG(15);
 }
else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x12") != NULL)// 18
 {
    //10010
             LATG(12);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x13") != NULL)// 19
 {
    //10011
    LATG(7);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x14") != NULL)// 20
 {
    //10100
     LATG(10);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x15") != NULL)// 21
 {
    //10101
    LATG(11);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x16") != NULL)// 22
 {

    //10110
    LATG(8);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x17") != NULL)// 23
 {
    //10111
    LATG(9);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x18") != NULL)// 24
 {
    //11000
    LATG(6);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x19") != NULL)// 25
 {
    //11001
     LATG(7);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1A") != NULL)// 26
 {
    //11010
    LATG(4);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1B") != NULL)// 27
 {
    //11011
     LATG(5);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1C") != NULL)// 28
 {
    //11100
    LATG(2);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1D") != NULL)//29
 {
    //11101
    LATG(3);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1E") != NULL)// 30
 {
    //11110
     LATG(2);
 }
 else if (strstr (msg, "DO=0x1F") != NULL)// 31
 {
    //11111
     LATG(1);
 }
}
```